# Rails optional property assignment for record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When using RoR, there is often a need to do assign multiple properties on an update and not update those that aren't required to update.

For example:

```
def some_method(params)
  record = Record.find(1)

  # All are required on create, but optional on update
  record.name = params['new_name'] if params['new_name'].present?
  record.record_type = params['new_record_type'] if params['new_record_type'].present?
  record.url = params['new_url'] if params['new_url'].present?
  record.description = params['new_description'] if params['new_description'].present?
  record.meta_1 = params['some_oddly_named_param'] if params['some_oddly_named_param'].present?
  ...
  record.save!
end
```

In some cases, there can be 30 to 40 properties that are optional on an update.  Is there a better way of handling a situation like this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `reject {|_,v| v.blank?}` or `select {|_,v| v.present?}`? I have to assume "30 or 40 properties" are contained in some Enumerable object.

Comment: @engineersmnky if those values were stored in a hash named `h`, that could just be done with `h.compact`. but this question is not clear enough about where these values come from.

Comment: @TonyArra `nil?` is not the same as `present?`. `present?` is `!blank?` and in rails this has a very specific implementation. I agree that it is not clear where these values are coming from; however one can generally deduce that this is a controller action and thus `h == params`.

Comment: @engineersmnky woops, I meant `compact_blank`

Comment: Made it more clear how the variables are being passed.  In this particular instance, present? is the correct implementation.